# How to execute two methods accepting runnable instance of same class in different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
class FooBar {
    private int n;

    public FooBar(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void foo(Runnable printFoo) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // printFoo.run() outputs "foo"
            printFoo.run();
        }
    }

    public void bar(Runnable printBar) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // printBar.run() outputs "bar"
            printBar.run();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code how to execute foo and bar methods in different threads on same instance of FooBar class?

Its a question from LeetCode. I am curious to know how it will be tested.
Link to problem : https://leetcode.com/problems/print-foobar-alternately/

Comment: `new Thread(() -> fooInstance.foo(yourRunnable)).start();`

Comment: This worked. Can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 errors here:

1. You don't need 2 methods for doing exactly the same thing.
2. To start a thread with a Runnable you never invoke the run method.

This is the correct way:

```
class FooBar {

    public void executeRunnable(Runnable printFoo) throws InterruptedException {
            // printFoo.run() outputs "foo"
            new Thread(printFoo).start();
    }


 public static void main(String... args) {
    FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
    fooBar.executeRunnable(new Runnable1());
    fooBar.executeRunnable(new Runnable2());
  }   
 }
```

Imagine that Runnable1 writes "foo" and Runnable2 writes "Bar"

Comment: But it will create new thread n times. That is not what is intended. Only two threads should be there calling these methods seperatly and printing "foo" and "bar" n times simultaneously.

Comment: Editing my comment

Comment: Anyway the only important is "new Thread(runnable).start()" this creates a Thread and execute the run() method inside it.